# Related to the maximum number of triggers

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api

There's a maximum number of triggers by Script, something around 20-23, I don't know certainly, but I need to use more than that in a project, somebody can give me a little suggestion to how get around this obstacle?

Comment: More details please.

Comment: The limit must be on installable triggers per account. You may try more accounts. From the Q it's not clear why you need more triggers.

Comment: Imagine that i have 60+ Calendars that i need to get the Id's from them everytime a user add a new event . I'm using the 'Updated Calendar' trigger on a function. Somehow i can't put more than one ID on that last camp when i create the trigger, so depared  with that problem .